# Sorting li elements by class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, jquery-selectors, html-lists

I'd like to **reorder li elements through an array with jQuery**

My list code looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="list.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="list">
   <ul class="xyz">
     <li class="element1">content for 1</li>
     <li class="element2">content for 2</li>
     <li class="element3">content for 3</li>
   </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I now want to reorder the DOM elements through an array.

I tried, but I don't get it running:

```
var array = ['element2', 'element1', 'element3'];

$.each(array,function(index,value){
   $('.xyz').append($(value));
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed a `.` - to select a DOM element with a `class` you must use `.` - see the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) docs

```
var array = ['element2', 'element1', 'element3'];

$.each(array,function(index,value){
   $('.xyz').append($('.'+value));    // add . here
});​
```

Alternatively you could add the `.` to the array

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/pJdJn/)

Answer (score 1):

I would get the inner HTML of each `li` into an array, empty the `ul` of elements, then repopulate the `ul` with the sorted items of the array created in the first step.

Comment: `.append()` removes and then adds the DOM element if used on an already existing element ... [see the docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Thank you ManseUK. I don't see that mentioned in the link that you provide, and grepping the page for "remove" finds only one irrelevant comment. I will experiment with it, I appreciate the pointer.

Comment: search for the word "cloned" - the paragraph with the first occurrence explains it

Comment: Thank you, that is very handy! I upvoted your comment and your answer.