# Sorting div elements by class (jQuery / Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to sort the div elements in #list by class (cat1, cat2, cat3 etc...) using jQuery.

```
<section id="list" class="pix_wall pix_load_content isotope" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 570px; opacity: 1;">
<div class="cat8 entry post-id-34  isotope-item" data-sort="8" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
</div>
<div class="cat2 entry post-id-124  isotope-item" data-sort="2" style="position: absolute; left: 380px; top: 0px;">
</div>
<div class="cat7 entry post-id-79 isotope-item" data-sort="7" style="position: absolute; left: 760px; top: 0px;">
</div>
<div class="cat5 entry post-id-87 isotope-item" data-sort="5" style="position: absolute; left: 1140px; top: 0px;">
</div>
<div class="cat3 entry post-id-95 isotope-item" data-sort="3" style="position: absolute; left: 1520px; top: 0px;">
</div>
<div class="cat1 entry post-id-99 isotope-item" data-sort="1" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 285px;">
</div>
</section>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10109656/944681) solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
var sorted_entries = $('.entry').sort(function (a, b) { 
    var _a = /cat(\d+)/.exec(a.className)[1];
    var _b = /cat(\d+)/.exec(b.className)[1];

    if (_a < _b) {
        return -1;
    } else if (_a > _b) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});

$('section').html(sorted_entries);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsNsU/)

Comment: It would be better to move the elements around using `appendTo` instead of using the `html()` function as this removes events.